# Find which line of the SQL is running in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am executing a very long SQL script in SQL Server Management Studio, normally it takes a few second to be done.

But this time it is taking forever and never completes. Other people running this script has no problem.

So I wonder if there is anyway I could debug in SQL Server Management Studio to see which line in this long SQL Script is currently executing and taking forever?

Comment: Take a look at your execution plan and see where the most expensive part of the query is.

Comment: is this a stored procedure? If fo, you might wanna try to edit it and save it again.

Comment: Also look at blocking, when it normally runs fast and suddenly it doesn't , you very often are blocked by another process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to fire up SQL Server Profiler and trace your SQL with that.  As a bonus, you'll get a lot more useful information than simply which line is causing the problem.

Comment: This is my first time using this profiler.  In the profiler I see few line is repeatly executed forever.  But I couldn't find such line in my SQL Script...

Comment: You'll likely have to filter Profiler so that it only shows you the SQL that is running from your session. You can type `SELECT @@SPID` from your SSMS session to get the session ID, and then use that as the filter in Profiler. That should show you what you're looking for.

Comment: oo I need to filter, I got it now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If Profiler doesn't give you what you want, have a go with the Activity Monitor. Find your session in the Processes part, and then pull up the details to see the last T-SQ command batch.